# Why is Angular Material Dialog component not showing in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, angular, angular-material2

The dialog box works fine in Firefox. In Chrome, the click event just displays a small empty dialog box with no content or buttons. I was working through [this](https://medium.com/@ladyleet/popups-modals-and-navigation-using-angular-material-2-components-in-your-angular-2-project-faf510dbcdee) example when I had the issue.

DialogComponent:

```html
@Component({
selector: 'dialog',
template: `
        <h1 md-dialog-title class="primary-color">hey title</h1>
        <md-dialog-content class="accent-color">
          hey this is the content of the dialog
        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions>
          <button md-raised-button color="primary" md-dialog-close>
            close button
          </button>  
        </md-dialog-actions>
`
})
```

AppComponent html:

```html
<div>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">
    Example Dialog - Click Me!
  </button>
</div>
```

AppComponent function:

```ts
constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

openDialog() {
  this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);}
```

Is there something specific I have to do to make it work in Google Chrome browser?

Comment: Did you import DialogComponent into `entryComponents` and `declarations` in your `AppModule` file?

Comment: Yes I did. It seems to work fine in Firefox. In Chrome there is no title, content or actions displayed when the dialog is opened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue stopped when I removed the selector from the DialogComponent:

```
selector: 'dialog',
```

Answer (score 5):

Had a very similar problem, which was fixed after changing my selector name from 'dialog' to 'dialog-box.' Not sure of the specifics, but I assume Chrome contains some 'dialog' selector that will be reference if you use 'dialog' as a selector name.

Comment: same problem, same solution. Changing the name did it.